# How to make fully responsive for div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML and CSS like :

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='left'>left content</div>
    <div class='right'>right content</div>
</div>
```

Now, I fix the width of left by pixel. How can I make the width of `right` in responsive (Make it fully responsive)

CSS :

```
@media screen and (min-width:600px)
{
    .wrapper {width:900px}
    .left  {width:300px}
    .right {width: ? }
}
```

I must use CSS only or Jquery to do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DarkBee: you don't understand my question?

Comment: Depending on what your requirements are you can use any of the current answers. I'd recommend Av Avt's solution because it is slim and widely supported. If you can't hide overflowing content I'd go for C-link's css3 solution and if you must support IE8- I'd go for [this simplified version](http://jsfiddle.net/DpwEF/1/) of Pete's example. I also wrote an additional way using table display styles.

Comment: @DarkBee no, it's 42.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Darn it... U are totaly right!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use css3 calc() function like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:600px)
{
    .wrapper {width:900px}
    .left  {width:300px}
    .right {width: calc(100% - 300px) }
}
```

Before using this: [see this: Can I use calc() css](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: the first time I see it. thank you. I will test now.

Comment: This is a good option but will fail as it is not widely supported, but you can refer this demo I made it from scratch http://jsfiddle.net/uLpPb/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
.wrapper {
    width:900px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    clear: both;
}
.right{
    overflow: hidden; /*prevent float wrapping*/
}
```

Comment: can you demo this? it is impossible to apply

Comment: Hint: don't give the wrapper a fixed width so we can see that `.right` is actually fluid ;)

Comment: Ok. thank you so much. I am considering the best way before appreciate  the best answer for this question.

Comment: This problem has several answers. Depending on you situation you will want to user my solution, or display: inline-block, or float both divs. I prefer this solution if overflow: hidden does not hinder other things you want to do with it, because it looks cleaner. In case you don't want the div to have overflow: hidden though, display: inline-block is my second choice.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve what you want using the following styles:

```
.wrapper {overflow:auto; padding-left:300px; min-width:600px;}
.left {width:300px; float:left; margin-left:-300px; height:300px; background:red;}
.right {float:right; width:100%; height:300px; background:blue;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/DpwEF/)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with quite good support would be to use display table/table-cell [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/DpwEF/2/):

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    display: table-cell;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
}
.right {
    display: table-cell;
    height:300px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: yeah. good solution. But I think I will use CSS3 like  C-link's way. Thank for your suggestion